# How to include content of post from one WP blog into a post/page on another WP blog

Tags: copy, file-get-contents

I want to present the content of a post in a post/page on another domain. The original post is updated regularly so I cannot use copy/paste. Is there a way to do this?

P.S. both blogs are mine so I have no copyright issues and access to code on both sites.
P.P.S I only need the content not comments etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this in a blog network or two instances

Comment: It is 2 instances - 1 domain and 1 subdomain self hosted with seperate installations.

Answer (score 0):

You therefore, as two instances, have two options

1. Write a piece of custom code to extract the post from the underlying wordpress db 
   and place it into your post.
2. As posts are output as rss you could use that rss to display the required post in the other blog, there are plugins for rss import such as http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-import/

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where I can read up on how to do your first option? I think it would be more search engine friendly than the 2nd.

Comment: The database stucture can be found here http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description as for pulling that out just need to write a bit of custom php to pull it out (could be incorporated into a plugin) I would also check wp-extend to see if someone else has already done it . As for more SEO friendly I am not sure why you would think that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I assumed that RSS is not indexed or crawled since it is usually duplicate content but it is only an assumption. Could you please tell me what I should search for in wp-extend I don't really even understand what I am looking for so I couldn't find it (I'm still a beginner... )